# Maven, how to access class from an other artifact

Tags: maven, import, dependencies, artifact

I made 3 artifacts
Common
Config
and Full
in my Full pom I had:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr</groupId>
            <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr</groupId>
            <artifactId>pConfig</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And in my Full artifact code source I tried to access to Config class and It didn't work. Maven install works but I had an Error in Eclipse:
import fr.datacontrol.DataSources; I has: the import cannot be resolved...
Do you have an Idea?
Thank you

Comment: Have you run `mvn install` in the Common and Config projects? Do the Config and Common projects appear under *Maven Dependencies* in your Eclipse project? (Also, the pConfig artifactId looks like it is a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's working in Maven but not in Eclipse, that means you don't have the same build path in Eclipse that you have in Maven. Which probably means that Eclipse isn't using the information in the POM when it builds your project.

You might need to install the m2e plugin in Eclipse - though I *think* it's included by default from Indigo onwards.

Or you might simply need to tell Eclipse that it's a Maven project: right-click on project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven project (in Indigo)